# Compose HorizontalPager swipe conflict with swipe back event

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

I currently have an issue with `HorizontalPager` swipe behavior, when perform the Android swipe back gesture from either of the screen edges, the `HorizontalPager` also swipes to the next image. Here is the GIF of it. I'm using compose UI version `1.3.3`

```
HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = pageCount,
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
      ) { page ->
        DefaultAsyncImage(
          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
          imageUrl = urls[page],
          aspectRatio = PRODUCT_LAYOUT_ASPECT_RATIO
        )
      }
```

[image]

How can I prevent the `HorizontalPager` from consuming the swipe gesture when the swipe should only close the Activity?

Comment: So what is this arrow appearing from the right edge? Is it the back animation of your phone?

Comment: I'm using samsung galaxy s22, that is the default swipe back gesture behavior of the device

Comment: So you are executing a back gesture after you swiped the pager. What does your app do with that back gesture? And to clarify, what happens to your pager when you swipe it in a way that doesn't trigger the back gesture?

Comment: on android the back gesture replace the back button to close the activity. I want to close the activity but the HorizontalPager also swipe its content, and it happens on both left and right side. This doesn't happen with ViewPager or ViewPager2 but moving to compose it happens.